# Keep first occurrence of string in nested list of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, tuples, nested-lists

I have the below list:

```
d2 = [('PO:', [541, 297.5, 117, 14]),
 ('PD', [680, 297.5, 30, 12]),
 ('1/29/2021', [676, 317.5, 67, 14]),
 ('PDF:', [541, 317.5, 100, 14]),
 ('CSF-IPS', [204, 593.0, 357, 15]),
 ('1', [148, 593.0, 8, 14]),
 ('1', [148, 593.5, 8, 14]),
 ('10', [608, 593.5, 17, 14]),
 ('10', [608, 593.5, 17, 14]),
 ('20.00', [684, 593.5, 37, 14]),
 ('20.00', [684, 593.5, 37, 14]),
 ('200.00', [767, 593.5, 46, 14])]
```

I need to only keep the first occurrence of each item so my list should be:

```
[('PO:', [541, 297.5, 117, 14]),
 ('PD', [680, 297.5, 30, 12]),
 ('1/29/2021', [676, 317.5, 67, 14]),
 ('PDF:', [541, 317.5, 100, 14]),
 ('CSF-IPS', [204, 593.0, 357, 15]),
 ('1', [148, 593.0, 8, 14]),
 ('10', [608, 593.5, 17, 14]),
 ('20.00', [684, 593.5, 37, 14]),
 ('200.00', [767, 593.5, 46, 14])]
```

I tried to take only the keys of d2 and wrote a for loop but only able to get first item of each tuple, not the second item.

Comment: Is it enough if the first string is the same to discard dupes. Or must the entire tuple be the same too?

Comment: as long as first string is the same, it should be discarded

Answer (score 1):

Using a dictionary constructor on the reversed list will produce the desired result but in reversed order.  You can reverse it again to get the final result in the original order:

```
d2 = [('PO:', [541, 297.5, 117, 14]),
 ('PD', [680, 297.5, 30, 12]),
 ('1/29/2021', [676, 317.5, 67, 14]),
 ('PDF:', [541, 317.5, 100, 14]),
 ('CSF-IPS', [204, 593.0, 357, 15]),
 ('1', [148, 593.0, 8, 14]),
 ('1', [148, 593.5, 8, 14]),
 ('10', [608, 593.5, 17, 14]),
 ('10', [608, 593.5, 17, 14]),
 ('20.00', [684, 593.5, 37, 14]),
 ('20.00', [684, 593.5, 37, 14]),
 ('200.00', [767, 593.5, 46, 14])]

d3 = list(dict(reversed(d2)).items())[::-1]

print(d3)

[('PO:', [541, 297.5, 117, 14]), 
 ('PD', [680, 297.5, 30, 12]), 
 ('1/29/2021', [676, 317.5, 67, 14]), 
 ('PDF:', [541, 317.5, 100, 14]), 
 ('CSF-IPS', [204, 593.0, 357, 15]), 
 ('1', [148, 593.0, 8, 14]), 
 ('10', [608, 593.5, 17, 14]), 
 ('20.00', [684, 593.5, 37, 14]), 
 ('200.00', [767, 593.5, 46, 14])]
```

[EDIT] to support duplicate entries that are not consecutive, you can still use a dictionary constructor but you'll need to get the keys in order before updating with the reversed list:

```
d3 = list(dict((*d2,*reversed(d2))).items())
```

You could also do it using a set inside a list comprehension which would likely use less memory:

```
d3 = [(k,v) for s in [set()] for k,v in d2 if k not in s and not s.add(k)]
```

If the duplicate entries are always consecutive, you can use groupby (from itertools) as suggested by Kelly:

```
d3 = [next(v) for _,v in groupby(d2,lambda t:t[0])]
```

Answer (score 0):

There is more to this than meets the eye. Here's a tricky two-liner (that mimicks @dimelu's answer quite directly as I just noticed):

```
seen = set()

d2 = [seen.add(x) or (x, y) for x, y in d2 if x not in seen]
```

This relies on the behaviour of the `or` operator which evaluates to its first truthy operand which will always be the `tuple` as `set.add` returns `None`.

Comment: Getting the 2nd occurrence of 1, not first

Comment: Edited it to get the first one.

Comment: @KellyBundy You were right, the double reverse didn't work as I thought. New approach now should work.

Comment: Yeah, that works, although it's not a one-liner and I hate it when people misspell "true" :-P. Here's a one-liner closer to your original: `d2 = [*(dict(d2) | dict(reversed(d2))).items()]`

Comment: I think I 've had the true/truthy debate with you before :D (a guido pep that uses the term: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/) That's a clever approach, I like it. But I would have to stare down what's happening.

Comment: Maybe :-). If we did, I probably pointed out that the word doesn't appear anywhere on docs.python.org. Sadly [there are now a few hits](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Adocs.python.org+%22truthy%22). They're in (translations of) the new doc for that pep topic, so hopefully I can get both the doc and the pep fixed :-D. Anyway, "evaluates to its first truthy operand" doesn't sound quite right. Sounds like that's what it does in general, not just in your particular case. And in general, both operands could be false.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
visited = set()
list = []
for a, b in my_input:
    if not a in visited:
        visited.add(a)
        list.append((a, b))

print(list)
```

Output:

```
[('PO:', [541, 297.5, 117, 14]), 
('PD', [680, 297.5, 30, 12]), 
('1/29/2021', [676, 317.5, 67, 14]), 
('PDF:', [541, 317.5, 100, 14]), 
('CSF-IPS', [204, 593.0, 357, 15]), 
('1', [148, 593.0, 8, 14]), 
('10', [608, 593.5, 17, 14]), 
('20.00', [684, 593.5, 37, 14]), 
('200.00', [767, 593.5, 46, 14])]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
[(k, v) for k, v in dict(d2).items()]
```

or

```
d2 = [*dict(reversed(d2)).items()]
```

Which transform it to dictionary, which eliminates all the duplicates, and than re-built the tuples' list.